# Cucumber : I want to send report on email after my all the scenario get executed, Is there any method like 'AfterAll' which can be used in hooks.rb

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have created mail function to send my report

```
class Email
  include PageObject
  require 'mail'

  def mailsender
      Mail.defaults do
        delivery_method :smtp,{ 
          address: "smtp.gmail.com",
          openssl_verify_mode: "none",
          port: 587,
          domain: 'gmail.com',
          user_name: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' ,
          password: '*******' ,
          authentication: 'plain'
        }
      end

      Mail.deliver do
        from     'xxxxxxx.com'
        to       'xxxxx@test.com'
        subject  'Execution report'
        body     'PFA'
        add_file 'Automation_report.html'
      end
  end
end
```

I want this function will execute after all the scenario get executed.

This is my hook file

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require watir

Before do |scenario|
  DataMagic.load_for_scenario(scenario)
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
  @browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
end

After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    screenshot = "./screenshot.png"
    @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
    embed(screenshot, "image/png",)
  end
  @browser.close
end
```

If I use this function in After do then it sends the email every time after each scenario get executed

Comment: Why are you using selenium code to take screenshot , maximize the window while you are actually using WATIR code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `at_exit` in the hooks.rb file.

```
at_exit do
   # your email logic goes here
end
```

Additional notes: After hook will execute after each scenario that's the reason why it will send the email after each scenario executed. On the other hand `at_exit` hook will execute only after all the scenarios are executed.

You can directly implement the email logic in the `at_exit` hook. If you want to call mailsender method and not able to access it in the `at_exit` hook then you can create the email class/module as shown below.

consider that you have Email module under GenericModules

```
module GenericModules
  module Email
     def mailsender
         # implement your logic here
     end
  end
end
```

And then add Email module to the `world` in the `env.rb` as shown below.

```
World(GenericModules::Email)
```

Now you should be able to access the method even in `at_exit` hook.

Comment: now I am getting 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/features/support/hooks.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `mailsender' for main:Object (NameError)

```





I am using it like 

```
at_exit do
  mailsender
end
```

Comment: @Akshay Updated the answer with the `world` implmentation. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @AfterAll hook which is available with Cucumber v7.x.
Carefully upgrade your cucumber packages in your pom.xml.

Refer: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks and check Global Hooks.